# What is the API for PersistentQueue?

Tags: data-structures, clojure, queue

What is the API for PersistentQueue?

Naïvely, it appears to lose any data put into it:

```
user=> (def q (into (clojure.lang.PersistentQueue/EMPTY)
                    (repeat 5 nil)))
#'user/q
user=> (def q2 (pop (conj q :a)))
#'user/q2
user=> (get q2 4)
nil
user=> (get q2 0)
nil
```

I must not be accessing PersistentQueue correctly. Clearly it doesn't work with `get`. What is the right way to access a PersistentQueue? What *can* you do with it?

And is PersistentQueue documented anywhere, even informally? ("It's only fully documented in my answer" is fine. Really, I'm hoping that someone will write the missing documentation in an answer, or tell where to find it if it's not missing.)

Answer (score 4):

`conj` never mutates its argument, it returns a new data structure that is immutable, and may share data internally with the original. But I think you know this part already.

`get` only works on associative data, and returns nil rather than an error if used on non-associative data. queues are not associative. This issue is masked partially in your example by putting nil into the queue, which makes the nil returned by `get` ambiguous.

```
user=> (def q (into clojure.lang.PersistentQueue/EMPTY (repeat 5 :a)))
#'user/q
user=> (into [] q)
[:a :a :a :a :a]
user=> (def q2 (pop (conj q :b)))
#'user/q2
user=> (into [] q2)
[:a :a :a :a :b]
user=> (get q2 4)
nil
user=> (get q2 0)
nil
user=> (nth q2 4)
:b
user=> (nth q2 0)
:a
```

Typically the right operations to use with a queue are `conj`, `into`, `peek`, and `pop`.

```
user=> (def q3 (-> q2 (pop)
                      (conj :c :d)
                      (pop)
                      (conj :e)
                      (pop)
                      (pop)
                      (conj :f)))
#'user/q3
user=> (into [] q3)
[:b :c :d :e :f]
user=> (peek q3)
:b
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion about `into`. I just put that into my real code. I'll update the question, too (again, just to keep on point).

Comment: Is `nth` among the typical right operations for a PersistentQueue? My immediate use for PersistentQueue is to keep a little history of recent states, throwing them away after 5 timesteps. I need to be able to look up "What happened 3 timesteps ago?" Is that outside the definition of PersistentQueue?

Comment: That's a fine use for a queue, really. nth is not *super* fast on queues, but for small N it's fine. You might also take a look at my [ring-buffer](https://github.com/amalloy/ring-buffer) for a queue-like structure with automatic eviction of the oldest entries.

Comment: @amalloy Thanks! I'll have a look. It might be just what I need, as it's starting to appear that PersistentQueue is not (quite) the right tool for the job.

Answer (score 0):

The protocol for sequential collections is

- `(conj coll x)` - return collection `coll` with `x` added to one end or the other;
- `(peek coll)` - return the next item to be discarded from `coll`, if there is one;
- `(pop coll)` - return `coll` less the discarded end.

`peek` and `pop` always work at the same end:

- the front of a list (or general sequence);
- the back of a vector or queue.

`conj` works at the *same* end as `peek`/`pop` of a vector or list, but at the *opposite* end (the front) of a queue. That's what makes it work as a queue.

As has been said, `get` and `disj` have nothing to do with sequential collections.

You may be puzzled because a `PersistentQueue` doesn't know how to properly convert itself into a string. `seq` will show you what you've got. For instance,

```
(def q (into (clojure.lang.PersistentQueue/EMPTY)
                    (repeat 5 nil)))

q ;=>#<PersistentQueue clojure.lang.PersistentQueue@1b4d89f>

(seq q) ;(nil nil nil nil nil)
```

Comment: Ohh.., so `nth` works only because it pops repeatedly and then peeks? Does PersistentQueue support any other operations beside the three for sequential collections?

Comment: Any sequential collection is a sequence, or at least sequable. So it supports  all the sequence operations. `nth` is a hybrid: it works like `get` on vectors and the like; but as a repeated `next` or `rest` would on sequences (including sequential collections), *not* as a repeated `pop`.